# How do I write a maximizing polygon function in formal notation?

Tags: geometry

Think video games character builds, represented in a radar chart with four dimensions (str, int, dex, agi) with x number of four sided polygons (character builds).

One polygon represents the current build, while others are potential builds.

Im trying formally notate a function that will evaluate and select the best build over what I have now. In this instance, the best build is the largest polygon surface area.

I'm trying to write a function that will evaluate all builds and maximize the surface area difference between my current build vs potential builds.

Comment: The polygon with the maximal perimeter to area ratio with $n$ vertices is just the regular polygon with $n$ vertices...

Answer (score 0):

Each polygon is most naturally described by its set of radial... radii, which can be described by numbers $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n$ (in this case, $n = 4$). The radii can even be normalized to a size at most $1$, and so each polygon corresponds to a tuple $\vec r \in [0,1]^n$.

Are you asking for a formula which, given a collection of such tuples, computes the area of each one and selects the one with the largest area? This is more properly described by an algorithm or program than a pure math function, but the domain or input-space would be something like $([0,1]^n)^N$, as the function receives $N$ different polygons to select from.

---

Edit: here is the formula to find the area of a single polygon, represented by the radii tuple $\vec r = (r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n)$.

The area of a triangular segment with sides $r_i$, $r_{i+1}$ and inner angle $\theta = 2\pi /n$ (assuming equal angle division of the radar graph) is $\frac12 r_i r_{i+1} \sin \theta$. Then, sum over all subtriangles to find the area of the whole polygon. That is,

$$A(\vec r) = \frac{\sin\theta}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_i r_{i+1}$$

This assumes that the radii are given in order around the polygon, clockwise or ccw. To find the maximal area polygon from a set, simply compute this quantity for each polygon in a list while keeping note of a running maximum. There may be a more intelligent/efficient way to find the maximal area polygon, but this is the basic brute force search.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think yes...  I need an algorithm to find the largest polygon area.